# Calculating the amount of Board Turnover

Tags: stata

I have been trying to calculate the amount of turnover happening in exective boards between 2006 and 2009 in the financial sector.

For this I have data looking like the following:

```
Year    Bank     Director       DirectorID    (ISIN, RoA, Size etc)
2005    Bank1    John Smith     120 
2005    Bank1    Barry Pooter   160
2005    Bank1    Jack Sparrow   2070

2006    Bank1    John Smith     120 
2006    Bank1    Barry Pooter   160
2006    Bank1    Jack Sparrow   2070

2007    Bank1    John Smith     120 
2007    Bank1    Barry Pooter   160
2007    Bank1    Jack Sparrow   2070

2008    Bank1    John Smith     120 
2008    Bank1    Carla Jansen   250
2008    Bank1    Jack Sparrow   2070 

2009    Bank1    John Smith     160
2009    Bank1    Carla Jansen   250
2009    Bank1    Mike Stata     875
```

And this data repeats for each bank from 2005 - 2015.

Now I have already made a turnover dummy variable with 0 = no change and 1 = change by using:

`collapse(sum) DirectorID, by (ISIN, Year, Bank)
gen interest = inrange(Year, 2006,2009)`

`bysort ID interest (DirectorID) : gen temp = DirectorID[1] != DirectorID[_N]
replace temp = . if interest==0
bysort ID : egen changed = max(temp)`

However, I would like to make turnover an actual variable on how many changes were made i.e.: (assume bank2 made no change `Turnover=0`, bank3 made 6 changes (6 new managers came in)`Turnover=6`  and bank4 made 4 changes (4 new managers came in)`Turnover=4`.

```
Bank    Turnover (ISIN, RoA, Size, etc)
Bank1   2
Bank2   0
Bank3   6
Bank4   4
```

Is this possible with Stata (or SPSS if that happens to be the case)?

- ISIN codes are my ID variable as they are linked to each specific bank.
- Two new people entered the board of Bank1. For now it would show as `Turnover = 2` as only 2 new people entered the organization's board. Had three people joined in the previous example, in that case `Turnover = 3` as each change made to the Board counts as `"+1" turnover` regardless of the people leaving. Only people that join (whether they replace someone or are just an addition to the board) are of interest in my thesis.

However, this could also be calculated differently if that makes it easier. Depends on how I write my methodology. It would be fine if the variable turnover says how many changes were made per year i.e. `Turnover2005`: 2005 - 2006, `Turnover2006`: 2006 - 2007, `Turnover2007` 2007- 2008 and `Turnover2008` 2008 - 2009

Finally, it's possible that TMTs grow, i.e. 2005 bank 1 has 14 managers on the board and in 2006 they hire 3 new managers but only let 1 go. Now the board has 16 managers and made 3 changes (3 new managers)

Answer (score 0):

This might help. The following code builds a dataset consisting of data with four banks and five years. It is panel data. The `xtset` command lets you use time series operators which are well documented here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ik8r4WvrPkc). (Note: for sake of clear exposition, in this example Bank 1 had no changes, Bank 2 had two changes, Bank 3 had three, etc.).

```
// Clear the session and other memory.
set more off
clear all

// Input reproducible data.
input year bank_num ceo_num

  2005          1       200
  2006          1       200
  2007          1       200
  2008          1       200
  2009          1       200
  2005          2       222
  2006          2       222
  2007          2       222
  2008          2       333
  2009          2       444
  2005          3       300
  2006          3       301
  2007          3       302
  2008          3       302
  2009          3       303
  2005          4       999
  2006          4       888
  2007          4       777
  2008          4       666
  2009          4       555

end

// Declare the panel structure.
xtset bank_num year

// Gen variable indicating if ceo_num stayed same.
// Resulting variable is 0 when there was no change.
gen no_turn = (ceo_num - f1.ceo_num)
// Gen dummy to indicate if ceo_num changed.
gen is_turn = (no_turn != 0 & no_turn < .)
// Gen a variable that counts changes.
egen turn_nums = sum(is_turn), by(bank_num)

// List data to inspect results.
list
```

Edit: Re-characterized comment for no_turn variable.